# edit datatable with code in managedBean jsf2 primefaces

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have a datatable which I want to edit the value of their component by programing when the user check or uncheck one of their chceckbox 
here is the datatable :

```
<p:dataTable  var="car" style="width: 270px;margin-top: 15px;margin-left: 60px" binding="#{editCommandController.hd}" value="#{editCommandController.lp}" id="carList" editable="true">  

                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Stock Papiers 
                    </f:facet>  

                    <p:column headerText="Libéllé" style="width:70px">                                
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.libelle}" style="width: 70px;" label="Year"/>                                   
                    </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="Stock" style="width:40px">                             
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.stock}"  label="Year"/>                        
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Choisir" style="width:40px;margin: auto;">       
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="karim" binding="#{editCommandController.tmp}" value="#{car.checked}" disabled="#{editCommandController.result gt car.stock}" >
                            <p:ajax  listener="#{editCommandController.checkListener}"/>
                        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox> 

                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

and here is the managedBean :

```
public void checkListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    System.out.println("je suis "+e.getComponent().getClientId()+" utilisé : et tmp :" );

     List<Papier> lp1;
    lp1 = new ArrayList();
     lp1 = (List<Papier>) getHd().getValue();
   // getHd().se
     System.out.println("lp1.size() : "+lp1.size());
     Boolean a = true;
     System.out.println("ce bool a = "+a);
    for(int i = 0 ; i< lp1.size();i++){
       System.out.println("alors le cheched est : "+lp1.get(i).getChecked());
       if(lp1.get(i).getChecked()){
           if(lastChecked != null){                   
               for(int j = 0;j<lp1.size();j++){
                   if(lp1.get(j).getId().equals(lastChecked)){
                       lp1.get(j).setChecked(false);
                       break;
                   }
               }
               lastChecked = lp1.get(i).getId();
           }else{
               lastChecked = lp1.get(i).getId();
           }

       }

    }
     System.out.println("avant d'affecter voila ce quilya : ");
      for(int i = 0 ; i< lp1.size();i++){
          System.out.println("alors le cheched n "+i+" est : "+lp1.get(i).getChecked());
        }

      org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable editdt = new DataTable();
      editdt.setValue(lp1);
      setHd(editdt);
    //getHd().setValue(lp1);

}
```

also in the managedBean I have :

```
private org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable hd;

public org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable getHd() {
    return hd;
}

public void setHd(org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable hd) {
    this.hd = hd;
}
```

like you see above, I use the binding attribute to link the datatable with the managedBean but when I use

```
org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable editdt = new DataTable();
      editdt.setValue(lp1);
      setHd(editdt);
    //getHd().setValue(lp1);
```

I don't see my changes on the datatable
do you have any idea
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating your datatable on the client side to reflect the changes you made on the server side. Refresh the datatable via ajax using `update= "carList"` to the ajax event.

Comment: I tested this attribute like you are writing but no resut

Comment: first of all, you don't need to do `org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable editdt = new DataTable(); setHd(editdt);` every time you perform an ajax update. simply changing the value of `lp1` will reflect the update, the `value` attribute you set on the datatable is enough to ensure that. Also for best, error free results in JSF2 ajax, make your bean `@ViewScoped`. That being said, to be absolutely sure the response for your datatable ajax update is being sent, use a dev console (firebug etc) and on the Network tab, check to see if the response contains the markup for your datatable